# [vue]: how to add dynamic class using css modules along with normal class css on the same element in Vue?

Tags: javascript, html, css

For example when i use the scope 
i write the template with the scope rules, and the code will be

```
<div
  class="item ripple"
  v-show="tabList.length > 0"
  :class="{'item-on':currentTabActive==index}"
  v-for="(item,index) in tabList"
  :key="index"
  @click="checkTab(index)"
  >
</div>
```

but when i use the css modules, i try the code style like

```
<div :class="[{'$style.red': true},'$style.bold']">hhhhhh</div>
```

or that

```
<div :class="{'$style.red': true},'$style.bold'">hhhhhh</div>
```

or like that

```
<div :class="{'$style.red': true, '$style.bold'}">hhhhhh</div>
```

I wonder what's the right way to do?

Comment: How's it been going with your problem? Did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want? Don't put `$style.red` inside string `'$style.red'`, instead if you want to interpolate it, use `[$style.red]`. `$style.red` works jut like normal javascript variable.

```
<div 
  v-show="tabList.length > 0" 
  :class="[
    'item', 
    'ripple', 
    {[$style.red]: isRed}, 
    $style.bold, 
    {'item-on': currentTabActive==index}
  ]"
  v-for="(item,index) in tabList" 
  :key="index"
  @click="checkTab(index)">
</div>
```